# Merge Replication not receiving updates via Transaction Replication when republishing

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication, transactional-replication

I'm trying to migrate from server Z, which replicates out to a dozen subscribers in two data center, to servers A & B, one in each data center.  In order to survive outages between data centers we were looking at doing Merge Replication between A & B.

My initial plan was to take Z and use transactional to go to A, which would then replicate out to B.  Then, as we migrate processes to use A, we could roll one process at a time.

**However**, while I can make updates directly to A or B and have them go to the other server, updates to A via Transaction Replication (Z) do NOT make it to B!

Identities are set as NOT FOR REPLICATION, but the rest of it is pretty much standard.

Comment: Why would you go transactional between Z and A, then merge between A and B? You could set a merge replication scheme Z->A->B and then just get rid of Z.

Comment: Interesting idea, @PhilippeGrondier.  Hadn't considered it, mostly because I want to make sure everything is rock-solid first, and don't want any work to accidentally go "upstream". But that's an interesting idea.

Comment: merge replication is indeed 'rock solid', and transactional replication makes sense only in limited cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

You need to set the Merge article property **@published_in_tran_pub** to **true** for all Merge articles participating in the Transactional publication.  You can use [sp_changemergearticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174386.aspx) to do this at Server A:

```
    EXEC sp_changemergearticle 
        @publication = 'MyPublication', 
        @article = 'MyArticle', 
        @property = 'published_in_tran_pub', 
        @value = 'true';
```

You can execute this change at will, without generating a new snapshot or reinitializing subscriptions.